# Radio button Toggle function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am Trying to work with radio button toggle and I found a almost exact example what I need :

**HTML**

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">
2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="twoCarDiv"  />
3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="threeCarDiv" />
<div id="twoCarDiv" class="desc">
    2 Cars Selected
</div>
<div id="threeCarDiv" class="desc">
    3 Cars Selected
</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.desc").hide();
$("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#" + test).show();
});
});
```

js fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/XD4kr/

In this Example I can make the toggle and shift between the buttons and open their Divs but What I am wanting is that  when the page loads , first div should open with selected with first radio button which is not doing now. then I can switch between them . Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply add `$('#twoCarDiv').show();` at the start ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $('#twoCarDiv').show();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/SYZmW/)

Comment: Thank you it's perfect , useful and easy one :)

Comment: Perfect unless you choose to change the default-checked radio button.

Comment: Sorry it was a miss understanding . I thought that post was the fist one . I never notice that older post goes down in stack over flow . I am sorry about that I am kind of new here :)

Comment: No, I was replying to your comment here (not criticising your choice of accepted/up-voted answers): this answer works, but it works as you want it only so long as you don't later decide to change which radio button should be checked on page-load.

Comment: @DavidThomas OP wasn't answering to you, but to me : after having accepted this answer, he accepted Ted's identical one and I asked why.

Comment: @dystroy: *ah*, that explains it, I wasn't entirely sure it was aimed at me, but made the assumption on limited information. When will I learn that it (really) is *not* all about me..? =/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("input[name$='cars']").change(function() {
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#" + this.value).show();
    }).filter(function(){
        return this.checked;
    }).change();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XD4kr/1/).

The above jQuery uses the `change()` method (in order that using `label` elements to switch the `checked` radio `input` will still work.

Hides the relevant elements.

Finds the element(s) with the relevant `id` (and `this.value` is cross-browser compatible, there's no need whatsoever to wrap that in a jQuery call; and unless you're using the same value more than once there's no savings to be made caching the value).

Filters the initially-selected elements, finds the one that's checked, and then triggers the `change` event.

The use of `change()` becomes more apparent when the HTML is modified to use `label` elements (so that clicking on the text causes the checked radio to change):

```
<div id="myRadioGroup">
    <label>2 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="twoCarDiv"  /></label>
    <label>3 Cars<input type="radio" name="cars" value="threeCarDiv" /></label>
    <div id="twoCarDiv" class="desc">
        2 Cars Selected
    </div>
    <div id="threeCarDiv" class="desc">
        3 Cars Selected
    </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/XD4kr/2/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.desc").hide();
$('#twoCarDiv').show();
$("input[name$='cars']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#" + test).show();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't hide both first and only hide the second one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#threeCarDiv").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do this is by storing the value 2/3 in custom `data-` attribute and set value of `div#desc` to `data-value` of radio button clicked `+ ' cars selected.'`

This way, you can just use 1 `div.desc` and change its value. It also reduces soze of jQuery code.

Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VHktM/1/)

#### EDIT

**HTML**

```
  <div id="myRadioGroup">
    2 Cars<input data-value="2" type="radio" name="cars" checked="checked" value="twoCarDiv"  />
    3 Cars<input data-value="3" type="radio" name="cars" value="threeCarDiv" />

    <div id="desc">
        2 Cars selected.
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
   var $desc = $('div#desc');
    $(document).on('click', 'input', function() {
        $desc.text($(this).data('value') + ' cars selected.');
    });
```